# How can I parse a CSV file that contains multiple concatenated tables, each with their own header row?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, parsing

I'm working on a desktop app that will take in multiple files and store information from them into a SQL database (basically like an automatic ETL process).

The problem that I found with parsing the files is that one file contains more than one "table" or headers as opposed to files that I've found the code to on the internet (the first line is usually what the column names are and the rest are all the data).

Does anyone have any idea how I can parse it?

Comment: I don't know if the popular `CsvHelper` NuGet package handles that - but if not, I would do 2-passes: the first pass would use a simple regex to look for those headers (assuming those headers never appear inside a cell value...) and store their offsets and lengths of the tables they represent, then subclass `Stream` that proxies the `FileStream` to restrict seeks/reads to the defined range of that table within the file (so you could continue to use existing CSV libraries provided you can pass them a `Stream` object).

Comment: Also, StackOverflow isn't Twitter (_thankfully..._) so we don't use hashtags here - instead we use normal tags, which are automatically applied to your post. I've taken the liberty of removing them from your post.

Comment: That's not a normal CSV, but if @Dai5 's answer doesn't work for you you could pre-process the file into a set of temp files (splitting at the boundaries) instead of using a subclassed stream.

Comment: @DaveS You missed a fatal flaw in my plan: you can't use `Regex` with `Stream` - only `String` - but the idea of loading a data-file into memory as a `String` is nightmare fuel

Comment: The pre-processing could use  basic string comparisons if the header lines are identical.  Pass 1 - read line by line to find the breaks, and either build the table of offsets for the stream subclass, or split into multiple temp files.  Pass 2 - start over to process as either a subclassed stream or as a set of temp files   Of course if there is only 1-2 weird not-normal CSVs option 3 is "use a text editor to fix them"

Comment: Is there something that indicates that one table ends and the next begins? Such as an empty line? Without that, it might be difficult to programmatically identify the end of one table and the start of the next, especially if the number of columns in the two tables is the same.

Comment: @DaveS y'know what's weird? Windows _still_ doesn't come with a built-in large-file-editor that uses memory-mapped files or a windowed or paged view of a larger file - if I've got a 100MB JSON file (don't ask) that needs a very quick tweak Notepad will just keel over - anyway I'm getting distracted and should get back to my day-job by now...

Comment: @Dai5 - Notepad++ can handle files of any size, but does get sluggish when it's hundreds of MB like a large database export.

Comment: @Dai Wordpad works mostly fine if you really want, but yeah just use Notepad++ like everyone else. Any application is going to get sluggish if you have such a big file, even if you don't load it all at once, every time you scroll to the end it needs to load the rest of the file.

Comment: I think CsvHelper lets you just call `ParseHeaders` again

Comment: @Charlieface But that's my point: proper large-file editors _don't_ need to load the entire file into memory or even scan through a file to get to the end: they can use memory-mapped files and/or jumping to the end of a file to instantly allow users to edit any file of any size instantly.

Comment: @Dai Notepad++ doesn't load the whole thing AFAIK, it just gets sluggish because you are scrolling and it needs to keep loading data

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a library that might work for you: [Sylvan.Data.Csv](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan). It supports CSV files that contain "multiple tables". For this feature to work, it requires that each table have a different number of columns, or a single empty line between them.

The following example shows how to use "MutliResult" mode:

```
using Sylvan.Data.Csv;

var data =
    """
    a,b,c
    1,2,3
    d,e,f,g
    4,5,6,7
    """;

// MutliResult will identify a new "table" any time the number of columns changes
// any empty lines between tables are skipped.
var opts = new CsvDataReaderOptions { ResultSetMode = ResultSetMode.MultiResult };

// CsvDataReader can be used as a DbDataReader, so can be fed directly to SqlBulkCopy.
System.Data.Common.DbDataReader csv = CsvDataReader.Create(new StringReader(data), opts);

do
{
    Console.WriteLine(csv.GetName(0));
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(csv.GetString(0));
    }
    Console.WriteLine("---");
} while (csv.NextResult());
// outputs:
// a
// 1
// ---
// d
// 4
// ---
```

If, however, two consecutive tables contain the same number of columns, and there is no empty line separating them, then this feature will not work, as it will see the subsequent table as a continuation of the first.

In that case, you can use a feature of the Sylvan.Data library, to identify where the next table starts.

This example uses the "TakeWhile" extension method to identify when the next table starts.

```
using Sylvan.Data;
using Sylvan.Data.Csv;

var data =
    """
    a,b,c
    1,2,3
    d,e,f
    4,5,6
    """;

var csv = CsvDataReader.Create(new StringReader(data));

// the batchReader will read until it finds a row starting with "d".
// you can customize this logic to identify when the next table starts in your data.
// The batchReader here is a wrapper around the csv reader, and will yield rows as long as the "TakeWhile"
// predicate is true
System.Data.Common.DbDataReader batchReader = csv.TakeWhile(r => r.GetString(0) != "d");

// process the table using the standard DbDataReader APIs.
while (batchReader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(csv.GetName(0));
    Console.WriteLine(batchReader.GetString(0));
}

Console.WriteLine("---");

// The csv reader is now positioned on the start of the next table
// calling initialize will re-initialize the CsvDataReader with the current row
// this will cause the "d,e,f" headers to be loaded.
csv.Initialize();

// consume the rest of the CSV data.
// Or, you might need to use another TakeWhile.
while (csv.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(csv.GetName(0));
    Console.WriteLine(csv.GetString(0));
}

Console.WriteLine("---");
```

This second example produces the same output as the first example.